# Time Series chart interpretation

Tags: time-series, python, arima

I was using Python to do a time series analysis. I observe the following pattern. Since the ACF cuts off at lag 12 and PACF tails off, does this mean I should fit a MA(12) to this series?

[image]

Well I actually fitted a MA(12) to the curve and I am getting the following:
[image]

Most coefficients are actually insignificant. Besides I don't quite understand how these nans come out.

Comment: Post your data please.

Comment: You probably want a seasonal MA(1)

Comment: Think of nans being an abbreviation for NANSENSE . nans really means not a number or something equivalently suggesting a non-sensical model.